# Php remove node from xml containing string

Tags: php, xml

I have an XMl file with url nodes.
I need to find url node containing the word "Server" and remove them from the file.

```
<?php    
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->load("../xml/cars689737484897767756.xml"); 
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($document); 
    foreach ($xpath->query('.//images[contains(., "Server")]') as $dataNode) {
      $dataNode->parentNode->removeChild($dataNode);
    }
     $document->saveXML();
?>
```

It does not save the removed node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$document->saveXML();` returns the resulting string. You need to handle that result in the way you need. One way could be [`file_put_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.xml', $document->saveXML());
```

Or you can as well use [`DOMDocument::save()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) like so:

```
$document->save('/path/to/file.xml');
```

but the former gives more control, since one can chose the node to dump.

Comment: … or just use the `save` method instead.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.   file_put_content().. will remember

Comment: @DanieGloy Reminder: Feel free to accept or upvote if the answer solves your problem… But I am happy if I could help anyway…